# Why is image segmentation needed for object detection?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, object-detection

What is the point of image segmentation algorithms like SLIC? Most object detection algorithms work over the entire set of (square) sub-images anyway.

The only conceivable benefit to segmenting the image is that now, the classifier has shape information available to it. Is that right?

Most classifiers I know of take rectangular input images. What classifiers allow you to pass variable sized image segments to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, SLIC, and the kind of algorithms I'm guessing you refer to, are not *segmentation* algorithms, they are ***oversegmentation*** algorithms. There is a difference between those two terms. *segmentation* methods split the image in *objects* while *oversegmentation* methods split the image in small *clusters* (spatially adjacent group of pixels with similar characteristics), these *clusters* are usually called **superpixels**. See the image** of superpixels below:

[image: Image of superpixels]

Now, answering parts of your original question:

### Why to use superpixels?

- **They reduce the dimensionality of your data/complexity of the problem**. From `N = w x h` pixels to `M` superpixels, with `M << N`. This is, for an image composed of `N = 320x480 = 153600` pixels, `M = 400` or `M = 800` superpixels seem to be enough to *oversegment* it. Now, letting for latter *how to classify* them, just consider how *easier* your problem has become reducing from `N=100K` to `N=800` training examples to train/classify. The superpixels still represent your data properly, as they adhere to image boundaries.
- **They allow you to compute more complex features**. With pixels, you can only compute some simple statistics on them, or use a filter-bank/feature extractor to extract some features in its vicinity. This however represents your pixel's neighbour very locally, without having in consideration the context. With superpixels, you can compute a **superpixel descriptor** from all the pixels that belong to it. This is, features are usually computed at *pixel* level as before, but, then features are merged into a superpixel descriptor by different methods. Some of the methods to do that are: simple mean of all pixels inside a superpixel, histograms, bag-of-words, correlation. As a simple example, imagine you only consider *grayscale* as a feature for your *image/classifier*, if you use simple pixels, all you have is pixel's intensity, which is very local and noisy. If you use superpixels, you can compute a histogram of the intensities of all the pixels inside, which describes much better the region than a single local intensity value.
- **They allow you to compute *new* features**. Over superpixels you can compute some regional statistics (1st order as mean or variance or second order covariance). You can now extract some other information not available before (e.g. shape, length, diameter, area...).

### How to use them?

1. Compute pixel features
2. Merge pixel features into superpixel descriptors
3. Classify/Optimize superpixel descriptors

In step `2.`, either by averaging, using histogram or using bag-of-words model, the superpixel descriptor is computed **fixed-sized** (e.g. 100 bins for histogram). Therefore, at the end you have reduced the `X = N x K` training data (`N = 100K` pixels times `K` features) to `X = M x D` (with `M = 1K` superpixels and `D` the length of the superpixel descriptor). Usually `D > K` but `M << N`, therefore you endup with some *regional*/more robust features that represent better your data with lower data dimensionality, which is great and reduces the complexity of your problem (classify, optimize) in average 2-3 orders of magnitude!

### Conclusions

You can compute more complex (robust) features, but you have to be careful how, when and whatfor do you use superpixels as your data representation. You might lose some information (e.g. you lose your 2D grid lattices) or if you don't have enough training examples you might make the problem more difficult as the features are more complex and could be that you transform a linearly-separable problem into a non-linear one.

** Image from SLIC superpixels: http://ivrl.epfl.ch/research/superpixels

Comment: Now that you have your irregular shaped (and variable numbered superpixels in every image?), how is it fed to the classifier? Would the training data have to be tagged by superpixel?

Comment: @agent_Jay That is one of the approaches. There are several different ways of solving, and depends on your purpose (if you are trying to identify which object is the one the appears in the image, or if you are trying to detect multiple objects *in the wild*). One approach could be to train a classifier on superpixels, for a given image predict the class for each superpixel, and then use Markov Random Fields (MRF) to refine the prediction. Another approach would be to train a Conditional Random Fields (CRF) directly per image+superpixels, this CRF is designed to learn appearance+structure.

Comment: @agent_Jay Have a look at this paper: https://www.cs.unc.edu/~jtighe/Papers/ECCV10/eccv10-jtighe.pdf it uses something like: similar image retrieval + k-NN on the superpixels + MRF to refine the likehoods per-superpixel obtained by the k-NN.

Comment: Thanks! Can you link to a paper that uses CRFs too?

Comment: You can have a look to this paper: https://graphics.stanford.edu/projects/densecrf/densecrf.pdf . It does `image parsing`, which is more complicated than `object detection` as it is `object dection+segmentation`, but it might be interesting. Webpage of the paper with some code [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/projects/densecrf/).

Comment: How are the other kind of segmentation algorithms, the ones that try to split images into objects used? It looks like algorithms like Mean shift and [Efficient Graph Based Segmentation](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~dph/papers/seg-ijcv.pdf) never result in segmentations that perfectly divide the image into objects, rather just similar parts. Is that the end result also fed to a classifier, like in the case of Oversegmentation algorithms?

Comment: @agent_Jay exactly. Both Meanshift and Efficent graph based segmentation provide very results thast could be categorized as *oversegmentation*. The term is relatively new and has been introduced recently. Unservised segmentation is another way of calling it. In general all this results are used to feed a classifier/regressor/CRF/something more powerful.

Comment: @agent_Jay In other words, both Meanshift and Feizenwalb's method *are* oversegmentation methods. Oversegmentation is just a generalized cathegory for those methods that split image in similar parts that belong to objects.

Comment: Oh. I thought that meanshift and Felzenswalb's method aren't oversegmentation because they resulted in fewer superpixels than SLIC. Lol. Calling it an unsupervised segmentation makes more sense. So which algorithms were your referring to as the other kind, at the very beginning of your post?

Comment: @agent_Jay Actually, if you refer to the SLIC superpixels paper: http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/177415/files/Superpixel_PAMI2011-2.pdf, you will find that they compare themselves to the state-of-the-art, which includes both Meanshift (as **MS02**) and Felzenszwalb's (as **GS04**), have a look on the second page. Besides that, All 3 algorithms have configurable parametes, you can tune SLIC to provide different kind of segmentation (more regular superpixels or coarse segmentation) and provide the number of desired superpixels (to get smaller or bigger ones).

Comment: @agent_Jay This is a bit subjective, but I would call *oversegmentation* methods all methods designed to *cluster* the image in small-similar-adjacent chunks of pixels, while *segmentation* methods those that explicity try to segment/extract an object from the image. For examples to segmentation you can google for Level Set methods for segmentation, or probably the better known GraphCut or [GrabCut](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html#gsc.tab=0) methods.